# How create dynamic route in next.js 13 using one request for list of items

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im using next.js 13.4.5 and src/app structure. I have service to get list of movies from server and i mapping list of movies in **src/app/top/page.tsx** file. Inside top folder i created dynamic folder **src/app/top/[id]/page.tsx** where i wanna show item detail. I wanna pass item.id, item.name, item.image in dynamic page. When i try to use **getServerSideProps** inside **src/app/top/page.tsx** i got error, that this method not working in next 13, but i don't found another decision to make it works.
I just wanna add, that i don't need to get id from params and use it in new service to get details for movie. I just wanna pass not only item id, but all item object.

If you can share some example it will be helpful.